# Custom redirect to memberstack field

Tags: javascript, webflow

I'm trying to get a page to redirect onLoad to the URL that is stored in a custom field on Memberstack. I'm not getting any errors in my browser but I can't get this code to work. Any thoughts on how to correct this?

```js
<!-- Your HTML code goes here -->

<!-- Place this script at the end of your HTML body or inside a script tag -->
<script>
  // Fetch the currently logged-in member data using Memberstack's getCurrentMember() method
  window.$memberstackDom.getCurrentMember().then(({ data: member }) => {
    // Fetch the value of the "tf-poc-1as-url" custom field from the member object
    let customUrl = member["tf-poc-1as-url"];

    // Add a 1-second delay before redirecting to the custom URL
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (customUrl) {
        // Redirect to the custom URL
        window.location.href = customUrl;
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
</script>
```